# How to handle hook_node_validate?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I am using some contirb module and in which `hook_node_validate` is used. I am overriding the function passed in hook by running `CUSTOM_MODULE_node_validate`. But the contrib module validate also keeps running, is there any way that I can stop it running and let only mine one to run?

```
function CUSTOM_MODULE_node_validate($node) {

  $nodep = 'object' == gettype($node);
  $isrelevantp = _anonymous_publishing_relevantp($node, $nodep);
  if ($isrelevantp) {
    custom_anonymous_publishing_cl_content_validate($node); // function replaced with my custom for validation 
  }

}

function custom_anonymous_publishing_cl_content_validate($node){
  ..........
}
```

ALREADY RUNNING IN MODULE:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_validate().
 *
 * The validate function will handle the honeyfield.
 */
function anonymous_publishing_cl_node_validate($node) {
  $nodep = 'object' == gettype($node);
  $isrelevantp = _anonymous_publishing_relevantp($node, $nodep);
  if ($isrelevantp) {
    _anonymous_publishing_cl_content_validate($node);
  }
}

function _anonymous_publishing_cl_content_validate($node){
  .......
}
```

Comment: You have misunderstood how hooks work. Generally, all hook implementations will be executed. One does not override another. So you'll need to rethink your approach.

Comment: yes exactly you are right that hook will always run from where ever its called. I am getting no idea to modify this, is there any way how can handle this kind of thing to override in my custom module, please suggest !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove a module's implementation of a hook like so:

```
function MYMODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'node_validate' && isset($implementations['anonymous_publishing_cl'])) {
    unset($implementations['anonymous_publishing_cl']);
  }
}
```